# Using integral estimation to show that $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {\ln k}{k^2} \le \frac {2+3\ln2}{4}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, inequality, estimation

> Show with Integral estimation that 
>   $$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  \frac {\ln k}{k^2} \le \frac {2+3\ln2}{4}$$

$$f(k)=\frac {\ln k}{k^2} $$
For the integral it is : 1

But the other part is the estimation, the lower and upper bound.

I try to set $1+f(1)$ at the upper bound and $1+f(\infty)$ at the lower. The answer is incorrect. What to do?

Comment: This is extremely unclear. What do you need to show? What is $f$?

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten half of the question.

Comment: Due to the fact that integrals are "small" intervals that sum-up so they want a estimation of lower and upper. :/

Comment: I am pretty sure that the sum is **less** than $\frac{\pi +1}{2}$.

Comment: My guess is that the lower bound should read $\frac{\ln(2) + 1}{2}$.

Comment: Yes indeed it is Mr.Nicolas, but the thing is I need to show it. Visually it should be stacks which are under and above the "function". And the upper/lower bound are to be set from them :/ 
I know really confusing, and I think this is just a way to understans the fundamentals of integrals.

Comment: Your post asks us to show that the sum is $\ge \frac{\pi+1}{2}$. We cannot do that, since it is not true.

Comment: My bad again, wrote the wrong equality. So now the question should be all right! Once again sorry!

Comment: Two observations: $(1)$. Your series is nothing else than $-\zeta'(2)$, see [Riemann zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function). $(2)$. In general, $~\displaystyle|\zeta^{(a)}(b)|~ = ~\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\ln^ak}{k^b}~ \approx ~\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln^ax}{x^b}~dx~ = ~\frac{a!}{(b-1)^{a+1}}$ . This can be shown by letting $x=\dfrac1s$ in Euler's first historical integral expression for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#History).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT 1**

The inequality can be proved using the general relation
$$\int_N^{\infty}f(x)\,dx\leq \sum_{k=N}^{\infty}f(k)\leq f(N)+\int_N^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$$
that holds when the series converges (namely, the integral is finite).

---

**HINT 2**

Also, note that *in this case* we have that $f(1)=0$, so
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(k)}{k^2}=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(k)}{k^2}$$

What you need to show, as said in comments, is that
$$\int_2^{\infty}f(x)\,dx\leq \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(k)}{k^2}\leq f(2)+\int_2^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$$

that is the relation of **HINT 1** using the fact that $N=2$, because is the initial term of the series.

Try to use this relation to prove the inequality. Good luck!

Comment: Damn, this seems to get me somewhere. So when a lower bound gives me 0 or the upper in fact, I should use the next that is 2. But if the upper N , f(N)= 0 do I use f(N-1) ?

Comment: what do you mean with "upper" $N$? Being a series, there's no upper term: it is an infinite sum...

Comment: That is off-topic. But it is true.

Comment: Just had too ask :)

Comment: is the answer enough, or do you need more help?

Comment: More than enough. I just solved it :) The case with f(1) = 0 so we had to use f(2) was the best part! Many thanks!